# pom.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I am facing below issues while executing a project in Eclipse:

```
Publishing failed with multiple errors
File not found: D:\Programs\j2ee\OnlineLibrary\target\m2e-wtp\web-resources\META-INF\maven\OnlineLibrary\OnlineLibrary\pom.properties.
D:\Programs\j2ee\OnlineLibrary\target\m2e-wtp\web-resources\META-INF\maven\OnlineLibrary\OnlineLibrary\pom.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
File not found: D:\Programs\j2ee\OnlineLibrary\target\m2e-wtp\web-resources\META-INF\maven\OnlineLibrary\OnlineLibrary\pom.xml.
D:\Programs\j2ee\OnlineLibrary\target\m2e-wtp\web-resources\META-INF\maven\OnlineLibrary\OnlineLibrary\pom.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

**System Configuration:**

- OS: Windows 8.1 (64-bit)
- Tomcat: 8.0.30 (64-bit)
- Java: jdk 1.8.0_45 (64-bit)
- Maven version: 3.3.9 on C:/
- Eclipse: Luna 4.4.2

**Steps followed:**

- *Configure maven in eclipse*
- *Updated the settings.xml file with custom repositories path placed on C:\apache-maven-3.3.9\conf*
- *In Eclipse:*

  - Click **Project-->Preferences-->Maven**. Selected the artifacts download options
  - Click **Maven-->Installations**. Added the maven installation (C:\apache-maven-3.3.9) and set it as default
  - Click **Maven-->Templates**. Below mention Templates are in "Off" mode
       "m2e profile","m2e-wtp activation,"m2e-wtp JAX-RS activation","m2e-wtp JPA activation","m2e-wtp JSF activation",
    "m2e-wtp's specific context root property".
  - Click **Maven-->User Settings**. Global Setting, Local Settings points to C:\apache-maven-3.3.9\conf\settings.xml
                                    Local Repository points to custom repositories path as below:
                D:\Programs\Maven\Maven_Repositories
- Created a new dynamic web project (project name: OnlineLibrary). Renamed the src folder as per Maven project structure.
- Right clicked on **project -->Configure-->Convert to Maven Project**. Right click on the project-->Maven. Selected Resolve 
                                                                      dependency from workspace projects.
- Added required dependencies to the project.
- Project Build successful as per Maven clean, build, install process.

But when I try to execute/Run the project on server error is displayed:

Answer (score 2):

This does not explain the problem but i resolved same problem with **Maven->Update Project(s)**

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Servers" tab and start server first. Make sure this is same server which your project is using. If server is not already added then add new server.

Now run you project, it will ask for server to "Continue" to "Restart Server". Choose "Continue" and it should run fine. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Post a mvn clean install, I also do a refresh on the project in eclipse with "Build Automatically" ON(enabled). A refresh triggers the Eclipse build and generates the pom.properties. However I have no idea why is the pom.properties not generated with mvn clean install.